OpenGL framework packages libgl1-mesa-glx and freeglut3 Not Available in Ubuntu 24.04 – Suitable Replacement?
I'm setting up the OpenGL framework on Ubuntu 24.04 and ran into an issue where two packages I need, libgl1-mesa-glx and freeglut3, are no longer available. I received the following errors:
# apt-get install --no-install-recommends libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev libglfw3-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libvulkan-dev libxrandr-dev libgle3 freeglut3 mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra
----------------------------------------
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mesa-utils' instead of 'mesa-utils-extra'
Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package freeglut3

I noticed that Ubuntu 24.04 does provide libgl1-mesa-dev and freeglut3-dev.
Ref :

https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libgl1-mesa-dev
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/freeglut3-dev

I was able to install libgl1-mesa-dev without issues, but I’m concerned that using the -dev versions may bring in additional headers and development libraries that might not be necessary for runtime usage.
Here are my questions:

Can I safely use libgl1-mesa-dev and freeglut3-dev as replacements for libgl1-mesa-glx and freeglut3?
Do these -dev packages include all necessary runtime functionalities, or are there alternative packages that might replace libgl1-mesa-glx and freeglut3 specifically for Ubuntu 24.04?

